Traefik can't connect to ACME Server
I have a portainer and traefik infrastructure on an ionos VPS. Suddenly overnight it broke. I can't access any dashboard or service on the server.
Investigating further led me to believe it probably is an issue with the certificate generation but I can't say for sure, if it's the only problem.
So I haven't touched it in a few months and now it's not working anymore. To be clear the docker-compose.yml in this post is slightly edited, I changed from latest for traefik to v3. Other than that it's the exact same as the one that has been running for over half a year.
So what have I tried already:

Searching for a solution obviously, no luck.
Reaching the acme server from the vps host, is working.
Reaching the acme server from inside the docker container not working.
Rebooting the whole machine no change.
Reloading the docker service no change.
Purging and re-adding networks no change.

If anyone has any ideas on what the problem might be, I'm very open for ideas or solutions.
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: "traefik:v3"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 15s
    restart: always
    command:
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefik-proxy
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --ping=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --log.level=ERROR
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.email=notyourproblem
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.storage=./acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./acme.json:/acme.json"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-proxy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`nope`) && (PathPrefix(`/shush`) || PathPrefix(`/nope`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.services.dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=td3v:noneofyourconcern"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-proxy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`nope`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.service=frontend"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.edge.rule=Host(`nope`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.edge.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.services.edge.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.edge.service=edge"
      - "traefik.http.routers.edge.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
      - internal

volumes:
  portainer_data:
networks:
  traefik-proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false

Network list of docker

Firewall rules in the ionos panel

logs:
Creating network "portainer-traefik_internal" with the default driver
Creating traefik   ... done
Creating portainer ... done
Attaching to traefik, portainer
portainer    | 2024/11/07 03:37PM INF github.com/portainer/portainer/api/cmd/portainer/main.go:369 > encryption key file not present | filename=portainer
portainer    | 2024/11/07 03:37PM INF github.com/portainer/portainer/api/cmd/portainer/main.go:392 > proceeding without encryption key |
portainer    | 2024/11/07 03:37PM INF github.com/portainer/portainer/api/database/boltdb/db.go:125 > loading PortainerDB | filename=portainer.db
portainer    | 2024/11/07 03:37PM INF github.com/portainer/portainer/api/chisel/service.go:198 > Found Chisel private key file on disk | private-key=/data/chisel/private-key.pem
portainer    | 2024/11/07 15:37:44 server: Reverse tunnelling enabled
portainer    | 2024/11/07 15:37:44 server: Fingerprint IShTAt+SYsnH0uQO8hqboTUl+fzRKtZT3mgqg33mF3k=
portainer    | 2024/11/07 15:37:44 server: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000
portainer    | 2024/11/07 03:37PM INF github.com/portainer/portainer/api/cmd/portainer/main.go:649 > starting Portainer | build_number=35428 go_version=1.20.5 image_tag=linux-amd64-2.19.4 nodejs_version=18.19.0 version=2.19.4 webpack_version=5.88.1 yarn_version=1.22.21
portainer    | 2024/11/07 03:37PM INF github.com/portainer/portainer/api/http/server.go:357 > starting HTTPS server | bind_address=:9443
portainer    | 2024/11/07 03:37PM INF github.com/portainer/portainer/api/http/server.go:341 > starting HTTP server | bind_address=:9000
traefik      | 2024-11-07T15:37:47Z ERR Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains error="cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp 172.65.32.248:443: connect: connection refused" ACME CA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory acmeCA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory domains=[""] providerName=leresolver.acme routerName=edge@docker rule=Host(``)
traefik      | 2024-11-07T15:37:47Z ERR Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains error="cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp 172.65.32.248:443: connect: connection refused" ACME CA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory acmeCA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory domains=[""] providerName=leresolver.acme routerName=frontend@docker rule=Host(``)
traefik      | 2024-11-07T15:37:54Z ERR Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains error="cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp 172.65.32.248:443: connect: connection refused" ACME CA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory acmeCA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory domains=[""] providerName=leresolver.acme routerName=frontend@docker rule=Host(``)
traefik      | 2024-11-07T15:37:54Z ERR Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains error="cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp 172.65.32.248:443: connect: connection refused" ACME CA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory acmeCA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory domains=[""] providerName=leresolver.acme routerName=edge@docker rule=Host(``)
traefik      | 2024-11-07T15:37:54Z ERR Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains error="cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp 172.65.32.248:443: connect: connection refused" ACME CA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory acmeCA=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory domains=[""] providerName=leresolver.acme routerName=dashboard@docker rule="Host(``) && (PathPrefix(`/`) || PathPrefix(`/`))"


So for anyone stumbling onto this question in the future I managed to solve it, thanks to a ton of more research.
What I had to do is a hard reset of the network config for the host machine:
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
ip link del docker0

That's it, after that I ran docker-compose and everything worked.
